# Styling h1 and h2 inside same class

Tags: css

I have a `h1` and `h2` tag that I would like to style on a specific `class`. But what is the correct syntax for that? Here only `h1` is getting `color: blueviolet`:

```
.adresse h1, h2 {
    color: blueviolet;
}
```

Comment: Your rule should be coloring every `h2`. If it isn't, then some other CSS rule has greater precedence and is overriding the more generic `h2 { color: blueviolet; }`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code can help you.

```
.adresse h1, 
.adresse h2 {
    color: blueviolet;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Selector `.adresse h1, h2` will select all occurrences of `h2` on your page and only those `h1` which are inside `.adresse` class.

If you wants to style `h1` and `h2` only when they appear inside `.adresse` then use the following selector:

```
.adresse h1,
.adresse h2 {
  color: blueviolet;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.adresse h1, 
.adresse h2 {
    color: blueviolet;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since CSS doesn't support nesting for selectors, each selector in a comma separated list must be explicit. Which is why `.adresse h1, h2` will select every `h1` within class `.adresse`, plus every `h2`.

To select multiple tags **within** any tag with specific class:

```
.adresse h1,
.adresse h2 {
  color: blueviolet;
}
```

To select a multiple tags **on** a specific class.

```
h1.adresse,
h2.adresse {
  color: blueviolet;
}
```

[CSS Selector Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)